# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Academia's [third moderator election](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Massimo Ortolano] [image: cag51]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking aeismail who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5950916555440128/0).

Comment: Thanks to all the participants for volunteering and congratulations to the winners. I wished this would happen in less interesting times.

Answer (score 12):

Congrats to the winners, thank you to M'vy for also running and thank you aeismail for all you past work.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to see aeismail go as moderator. I hope you can still participate at a high level.

And if the two new mods continue to contribute as mods as they have as members, the site will be in good hands.

Congratulations.

Comment: Please next time  you apply. :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to all for your confidence / votes ... my happiness at being elected is tempered only by my sadness to learn that aeismail is stepping down.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to all those who participated in this election, and especially thank you aeismail for the work done so far!

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations to both of you. You have many challenges lying in front of you now, and I wish you good luck to tackle all of them!

Thank you aeismail for all your good work as well, we will miss you.